# Map between circles

Tags: general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $C_1, C_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be concentric circles in the plane. Suppose that $C_1$ bounds $C_2$. Let $f: C_1 \rightarrow C_2$ be a map such that for some $y \in C_2$, $f(x) = y$ for all $x \in C_1$ and that $x$ and $y$ must be connected by a path that is entirely contained in the interior of the region bounded by $C_1$ and that does not intersect $C_2$. Can $f$ be continuous?

EDIT:

I should probably phrase this differently. If $f$ is defined as above, can the sequence of paths under the condition above be continuous?

Comment: Yes, like concentric circles $C_i$ centered on x-axis. $ (x-h)^2+y^2 = r^2$, for arbitrary $h,r$.

Comment: I don't think it really matters where they're centered. Just as long as $C_2$ is contained in $C_1$.

Comment: You write "$f(x)=y$ for all $x\in C_1$"...so $f$ is a constant function?

Comment: In any case, I don't understand the condition you're trying to impose by saying that $x$ and $y$ can be connected by a certain path...there exists such a path for every $x\in C_1$ and every $y\in C_2$.

Comment: Yes, every point on $C_1$ maps to the same point on $C_2$ by $f$. But the restriction that $x$ and $y$ be connected by a path in the interior of the region bounded by $C_1$ that does not intersect $C_2$ is why I think that this must violate continuity.

Comment: Trying to understand You want like expanding or contracting circles $ f(x,y)=(x-h)^2+(y-k) ^2 = sin(r) ^2 $ where $h,k$ are constant and $r$ is variable in a bounded  dilatory radial map ? There is no intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every constant map is continuous, so in particular your map is continuous.

However, you cannot choose such paths from each $x\in C_1$ to $y$ such that they give a continuous map $F:C_1\times [0,1]\to B$, where $B$ is the closed annulus between $C_1$ and $C_2$.  To see this, let $p:B\to C_1$ be the radial projection and consider the composition $pF:C_1\times [0,1]$.  Then $pF(x,0)=x$ for all $x$ and $pF(x,1)=p(y)$ for all $x$, so $p$ is a homotopy from the identity map $C_1\to C_1$ to a constant map.  Since $C_1$ is not contractible, no such homotopy exists.

Comment: I guess more specifically I should say that the sequence of paths generated can't be continuous. Or rather does there exist a continuous constant function $f$ that satisfies my condition.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for instance the radial map $$ x^2 + y^2 = h\, y $$ where $ h <1 $ maps all circles on x-axis to its dilated counterparts.

EDIT1:

Or if non-intersection among circles is very strict, the $\tau $ circles in bipolar co-ordinate map or grid (Fig 181):

$$ x^2- 2 x h + y^2 +T^2 =0 $$

The circles are distinct, non touching, same constant tangent length $L$ , variable set constant $h$ for each circle...  but this example is from  *non-euclidean* hyperbolic geometry, out of the given tag.

[Bipolar_Tau_Circles](http://gerris.dalembert.upmc.fr/gerris/tests/tests/wannier.html)